# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'AppKit' -Python playsound

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am using playsound in my python project but it gives me this error

I tried  - `sudo pip install --user --upgrade --force-reinstall PyObjC PyObjC-core1`

same thing happens

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/ashvinbhagat/development/person-personal-assistant-master/main.py", line 157, in <module>
    assistant_speaks("Hello, " + name + '.')
  File "/Users/ashvinbhagat/development/person-personal-assistant-master/main.py", line 33, in assistant_speaks
    playsound.playsound(file, True)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/playsound.py", line 55, in _playsoundOSX
    from AppKit     import NSSound
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'AppKit'
```

Comment: Are you using any IDE ? if yes, then verify what is the  project interpreter for your project

Comment: Yes, i am using PyCharm and it is python console